# Get error "Derived contract must override function _beforeTokenTransfer"

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I want to implement a burn feature in my ERC721 contract in Solidity. To do so, I have imported the function **burn** from **ERC721Burnable.sol**.

Since I have imported it I get the following error:
"*Derived contract must override function _beforeTokenTransfer*".
The same goes with **supportsInterface** function.

1. I did override both of them as you can see below. It works but I would like to understand why do I have to do that?

```
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal virtual override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable) {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
```

I checked Openzeppelin [repo](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/cc1c18098c0d6b52e751f96dd13b97306468f171/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L307), **_beforeTokenTransfer** is called inside **_burn** function. At first, I thought it was the main reason but the fact is that **_beforeTokenTransfer** is also called inside **mint** and I did not have that error before.

2. I have no idea why I have to override [**supportsInterface**](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/cc1c18098c0d6b52e751f96dd13b97306468f171/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L52).

Thanks

Comment: is your contract also inheriting from another contract?

Comment: Yes @Yilmaz! 
ERC721Enumerable.sol, ERC721Burnable.sol and Ownable.sol

Comment: can you remove `(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)` from `override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)` and try it

Comment: No I have to specify them but it's not the point though. As I said my code works but I do not understand why I have to override supportsInterface and _beforeTokenTransfer.

Answer (score 0):

`ERC721Burnable` inherits from two contracts:

```
abstract contract ERC721Burnable is Context, ERC721 {}
```

[ERC721.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol) contract has `_beforeTokenTransfer` and `_afterTokenTransfer` unimplemeted functions. you have to implement those in your contract.

[from this github issue](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/3107)

> ERC721Enumerable and ERC721Burnable both override the
> _beforeTokenTransfer and supportsInterface functions. Solidity requires you to "fix" that overriding conflict. If we were able to
> address that in our contract we would, but its a solidity requirement
> that the child contract explicitly resolves this.

Looks like you 2 of contracts are conflicting inhering `supportsInterface`